# Site Error: Unable to Load Site Preferences in MSM site

Tags: multi-site-manager, php, php-errors, localhost

I recently installed a version of EE on my local machine(Mamp Pro), v2.5.5 - Build Date: 20121220. I set this site up as per usual and started building my initial site templates etc ready for the master site which would encompass all the other child sites with MSM.

I then installed MSM by buying the software license and then enabling it in the main general settings of the cp in my site. I then created a new sub domain with MAMP PRO and then added a folder in it with index.php and admin.php, I then changed these settings in each:

index.php

```
$system_path = '../build/system/';
$assign_to_config['site_name']  = 'mysitename'; 
$assign_to_config['cp_url'] = 'http://missns:8888/admin.php'; 
$assign_to_config['site_url'] = 'http://missns:8888';
```

admin.php

```
$system_path = '../build/system/';
$assign_to_config['site_name'] = 'mysitename';
$assign_to_config['cp_url']    = 'http://missns:8888/admin.php';
```

When I try to access

```
http://missns:8888/admin.php or http://missns:8888
```

I get this error:

```
Site Error: Unable to Load Site Preferences; No Preferences Found for: mysite
```

Then in my main cp site theme where my main site is installed I go to the top right of the site and click my master site name and click 'edit sites', I then just get a server error page that takes me out of my site, it basically blows up.

Comment: As a side note if you're using MAMP Pro you don't need to add the port number to the URL if you go to Server > Apache and set the port to the default web port (80).

Answer (score 1):

Have you set things up following the [instructions in EE docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/domainsetup.html)?

Ensure that you have the relevant permissions on to allow access to your installations system folder:

> The new folder must allow files within it to access your
>   installation’s system folder. Check with your host to ensure you don’t
>   have “open_basedir” or other restrictions in place which could prevent
>   this.

Also, maybe try providing the virtual host name if you're setting this up locally. So instead of:

```
$system_path = '../build/system/';
```

Try:

```
$system_path = 'domain1.com/system/';
```

Where domain1.com is the name of your local virtualhost.

Also, make sure you make the changes to both sub domains as indicated in the docs.

Comment: Should I change $system_path in my main index.php file where I did the main install of ee as well or just the subdomains folders? I have been through the install so many times so I know it must be right.

Comment: Are you sure you've [copied the relevant files first](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/install.html)? Apologies if you have but with only a snapshot of what you may or may not have done it's always best to make sure the basics are covered first.

Comment: oh yeah all of that was done yes!

Comment: Did you resolve this, I have similar issues.